# Python class imported from another file is not recognizing attributes

Tags: python, class

This first section of code is from my file "othello_game_logic.py" Its the module I used to create the game logic for the game of Othello. My current goal is to create a graphical user interface(gui) for the game of othello, using my already created logic. 
This class GameState represents an entire game of othello.

```
class GameState: # represents a game of Othello
    board = [] #represents the board, is a two-dimensional list.
    def __init__(self):
        self._player_turn = 'BLACK' #keeps track of whos turn it is

    def __init__(self):
        self._valid_move = True #keeps track of whether or not a move is valid
    columns = 4 #columms and rows for the board 
    rows = 4
```

This next section is from a new module in which i will be coding the graphical user interface. I am doing this using tkinter.

```
class OthelloGui: # as of now almost everything for the GUI is represented inside of this class.
    def __init__(self):
    def _run_othello(self):
        '''runs the game of othello'''
        a = othello_game_logic.GameState() # creates an instance of the GameState class from the other file
        a.create_board(a.columns, a.rows) #creates the board, a 2-dimensional list
        print(a._valid_move)
        print(a._player_turn)
```

It produces and error message saying that `a._valid_move` and `a._player_turn` do not exist. However it does recognize the global attributes such as `a.columns`. Why is this?

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\ics32\project 5\othello_gui.py", line 112, in _canvas_resized
    self._run_othello()
  File "C:\Python34\ics32\project 5\othello_gui.py", line 40, in _run_othello
    print(a._valid_move)
AttributeError: 'GameState' object has no attribute '_valid_move'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\ics32\project 5\othello_gui.py", line 112, in _canvas_resized
    self._run_othello()
  File "C:\Python34\ics32\project 5\othello_gui.py", line 40, in _run_othello
    print(a._valid_move)
AttributeError: 'GameState' object has no attribute '_valid_move'
```

Comment: Why do you you have **two** `__init__`s?! And what is going on in `OthelloGui`? I strongly suggest you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Can you please post the traceback you are seeing?

Comment: Can you please post the definition of `othello_game_logic` and `create_board`?

Comment: The second `__init__` overwrites the first `__init__` so we'd expect `a._valid_move` to be defined while `a._player_turn` is not. Could it be you are not importing the file you think your are? Try `print(othello_game_logic.__file__)` and see if its the file you expect.

Comment: `columns` and `rows` are class level attributes. When you say `a.columms`, python looks for the attribute on the object instance and falls back to the object class if not found. If you assign `self.columns` you get that value, otherwise you get the class value.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to SO. I edited the post further explaining my goal and what everything is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your question falls into the category of "why isn't this code working?" which is covered in the [Help Center section on Asking "What topics can I ask here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In particular you should read the section on ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

From your post I'm inferring that you are either new to programming or new to Python, and there are couple of things that you can do on your own perhaps to answer your question:

1. Please [read the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html), specifically the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) section on [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). In this section you will learn about instantiation, what `__init__()` does and how to use it properly.
2. Learn how to debug. Many issues similar to yours can be solved by using a debugger. [Python `pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is a simple debugger that lets you step through your code line by line, set breakpoints, interrogate arguments and variables and execute arbitrary code in the the current scope to test behavior.

I was able to get the desired outcome from your code by removing the extra `__init__`:

```
>>> class GameState:
>>>     board = []
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self._player_turn = 'BLACK'
>>>         self._valid_move = True
>>>     columns = 4
>>>     rows = 4
>>>     def create_board(self, c, r):
>>>         pass
>>>
>>> class OthelloGui:
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         pass
>>>     def _create_circles(self, board):
>>>         pass
>>>     def run_othello(self):
>>>         '''runs the game of othello'''
>>>         a = GameState()
>>>         a.create_board(a.columns, a.rows)
>>>         print(a._valid_move)
>>>         print a._player_turn
>>>         self._create_circles(a.board)
>>>
>>> b = OthelloGui()
>>> b.run_othello()
True
BLACK
```

Note I also added extra information to someone reading my post, such as the definitions of all methods, so that there would be less questions about what my code actually does. Hope this helps, good luck in your coding adventures and please next time try to improve the quality of the questions that you post on SO, and you will get far more positive replies.